# Temporal resampling effects on linear trend estimation

Tags: regression, time-series, linear, trend

I'm looking to determine rate of change of a noisy seasonal time series with linear regression.

In the first figure, there is daily data for 30 years. The second figure is the same data aggregated annually by taking a mean. The third plot is the decomposed trend (additive).

The total rate of change is over 2 times greater when using daily data. Additionally, P-value is many orders of magnitude smaller using daily data.

What is the proper approach to determine total change? Is it better to remove seasonality first? If so, you still have the question of temporal sampling.

[image]